# how to send fixed values to a database from PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

Im trying to make a simple ordersystem where the user inputs basic contact information, to this I want to add a fixed value that will allways be sent to the database in this case the price for the product. Also I want the date when the order is placed to also be sent to the database. I have solved the the user input part with a simple input form but have no idea how to get a fixed value for price or pris in this case and the date when the form i submitted to always be sent to the database along with the users contact information. 
The code I have right now looks like this:

```
    <?php /*Detta är kod för Order*/ include('input.php');?>
<?php if(!empty($_POST)){

  //Contact
  $mail         = $_POST['mail'];
  $first_name   = $_POST['fname'];
  $last_name    = $_POST['lname'];
  $adress       = $_POST['adress'];
  $phone        = $_POST['phone'];

  //Zip code
  $zip           = $_POST['zip'];
  $city          = $_POST['city'];

  //Orders
  $type          = $_POST['type'];
  $price         = $_POST['price'];
  $many          = $_POST['many'];
  $date          = $_POST['date'];
  $img           = $_POST['img'];
  $paymentstatus = $_POST['paymentstatus'];


  $sqlContact = "INSERT INTO Contact (Mail, FName, LName, Adress, Phone) Values('$mail', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$adress', '$phone');";

  $sqlZipCode  = "INSERT INTO ZipCode (Zip, City) Values('$zip', '$city')";

  $sqlOrders  = "INSERT INTO Orders (Type, Price, Many, Date, IMG, Paymentstatus) Values('$typ','$pris','$antal','$datum','$img', '$betaldstatus')";

  $resultKontakt = mysql_query($sqlKontakt) or die(mysql_error() . mysql_errno());

  $resultPostNr  = mysql_query($sqlPostNr) or die(mysql_error() . mysql_errno());

  $resultOrders  = mysql_query($sqlOrders) or die(mysql_error() . mysql_errno());
}
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x8c53o2865hln58/Input.php
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5yyq33uux0tqd2h/Order.php

How have worked around so that I get a fixed value "49" for the price and also so that the user can input the current date but I don't want this to be visible for the user and also not in the HTML-form as the information for the price is stated on the site and the date is to se when the order is submitted but it has to be as an attribute because I also need to show the data "submitted orders" on an Adminpage.

Comment: Paste code into your question and not too big chunks of it, please.

Comment: I guess it's enough with just the PHP.

Comment: fixed values as in no decimal points ?? whats fixed mean ??

Comment: srry by fixed values I'm referring to the number 49 which I want to be sent along with all the users input but in the background. the number 49 I want to be stored in the "Pris" attribute in the "Orders" table.

Comment: It costs literary nothing for you to do a search/replace of those var names. It costs a lot for people reading the code to parse strange words...

Comment: I'm really srry, I will go in and make it english :)

Comment: 1. The mysql extension is deprecated, you should not be using it.
2. Your code is wiiide open to [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Never show your DB-password in a forum!

To your date-question: Use the DB-date `now()` of mysql so you get a reliable date:

```
$sqlOrders  = "INSERT INTO Orders (Typ, Pris, Antal, Datum, IMG, BetaldStatus) Values('$typ','$pris','$antal',now(),'$img', '$betaldstatus')";
```

To your Price: (still not clear to me what you exactly want.

```
$pris         = 49;
```

Comment: Thank for your answer and oops about the password, well this is a school project so it will not go live. But anyhow about the $pris as the code is written now the value 49 is set in the HTML form and is visible to the user, what I want to do is something like: Sudocode $pris = $_POST['49'];. In other words I want the value 49 to be posted to the database along with the data that the user puts in the form. So that on every post that is sent in to the database it says 49 under the attribute Pris. Probably the easiest thing in the world to solve but I don't get how to do it. :/

Comment: about the DB-date now() so it is not necessary for me to catch the date with PHP as all I can do is to use Now() in the database itself and add a stored procedure or something to add the date to the Date attribute? Or is there a way to do it with PHP other than letting the user put in the date by themselves in the HTML form?

Comment: It is the date of your Server. So the user has no input to make. (I think the same is your pris. Just get rid of the two fields: $_POST['date'] and $_POST['pris']).

Comment: By the way now() returns the datetime-Format so make sure your db-field has type datetime.

Answer (score 0):

You have disabled the text field 'pris' but still somebody may edit the '$pirs' variable using a proxy tool and change the price, so i suggest according to the product the user has selected get the price and insert into the table, do not receive the price using the form (using post variable).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, srry that I have to ask ut how do I do that in code? This is where I fall short. How can I receive the price of 49 in every submitted order? Also I might want to add that safety is not a concern as this will not go live. It is a school project that I have gotten a bit stuck on.